# Jupyter Notebook Won't Open in Newly Installed Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook

I installed the newest Firefox version (Quantum v. 65) on an Ubuntu machine and Jupyter Notebook will not open in it from either Anaconda or a command prompt.

I received the following error:

"Access to the file was denied

The file at /run/user/1000/jupyter/nbserver-11292-open.html is not readable.

```
It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access."
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the open issue regarding this: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5479

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue with Firefox snap.
Luckily, jupyter notebook, when run from the command line, also outputs a link that you can copy and paste on the browser (or just Ctr + click).

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///run/user/1001/jupyter/nbserver-30315-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=a0602687337c0045f9dc2106a5a7fb466a9a86dd74378f64
```

Not an optimal solution but an acceptable work-around.